# Maven is skipping unit tests

Tags: maven, unit-testing

I am facing an issue while running test using command line.

`mvn test -DskipTests=false -DskipITs=false` is only running some unit tests and skipping the rest. Are there any tricks or other options to force maven to take into account all the related tests.

Comment: Is that a typo, `fasle` instead of `false`? Why do you set `skipTests` to `false` if you actually want to run the tests?

Comment: Could you provide code example of `running some tests` and `rest tests` ? Maybe there is some differences ?

Comment: to tun the whole tests we can use: "mvn test" or "mvn test -DskipTests=fasle -DskipITs=false" (just to force maven to take into account all the tests)

Comment: To run a pecific test we can use : mvn test -Dtest=TestClassName

Comment: If you like to run the test simply call `mvn test`....

Comment: Does your IDE recognize them as tests? Have you missed the `@Test` annotations?

Comment: yes all tests are annotated @Test

Comment: In which folder have you located your tests?

Comment: Unit tests are all placed under the java/test/java folder. My problem is that when I run "mvn test" I got a successful build, but when I run test on a specific test for exemple "mvn test -Dtest=TestsClass" I got a failed build.